# Connect BY + Join Full Node with Oracle

Tags: oracle, left-join, connect-by

I get a caller, callee path from a table by using a `CONNECT BY` query.

Then using the result, I get info which is in another table so, I use left join.

When I use left join, I used callee as a condition. 
At this case, the root node's info is missed. Is there any good way to add root info, without using, union or subquery?

Comment: Show your query.

Comment: Improved Grammer.